# Some funny directories appeared in my home folder!

Tags: 12.04, home-directory

I've recently installed Ubuntu Sever 12.04, and I've been having trouble with [audio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123623/volumeicon-fails-to-start), and have been installing software to fix it.

However, after rebooting my computer in (a futile) attempt at getting `volumeicon` to work, I've found that my home directory has been populated with some directories that I am pretty sure I haven't created myself, and wasn't there when I freshly installed it. Namely, they are `Desktop`, `Public`, `Videos`, `Documents`, `Music`, `Downloads`, `Pictures`, and `Templates`.

How did these directories get there? Is it something I installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are part of the desktop installation. The desktop home looks like this:

[image]

<sub>Old image from the web. The www and node directories are extra in the image</sub>

Some extra information that might help pin point where it came from. The directories created are probably from

`cat /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults`

```
# Default settings for user directories
#
# The values are relative pathnames from the home directory and
# will be translated on a per-path-element basis into the users locale
DESKTOP=Desktop
DOWNLOAD=Downloads
TEMPLATES=Templates
PUBLICSHARE=Public
DOCUMENTS=Documents
MUSIC=Music
PICTURES=Pictures
VIDEOS=Videos
# Another alternative is:
#MUSIC=Documents/Music
#PICTURES=Documents/Pictures
#VIDEOS=Documents/Videos
```

[More info on freedesktop.org](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs)

Unless you actually installed gnome desktop on that server (but I bet you'd remember that) you might have touched a package with `xdg` in the name.

Comment: I've ran `dpkg -l | grep xdg` and it lists `xdg-user-dirs` as one of the packages. Maybe this was it? At any rate, it looks like uninstalling them (even with --purge) doesn't clean up those directories.

Comment: Nope it will not: removing them should be up to the user. You never know if there's a file in there that needs saving (better safe then sorry ;) )

Answer (score -1):

Are these folders actually directly in the `/home directory`? or in `/home/"Username"` directory?  If they're under your `/home/"Username"` directory these are default folders that are installed with every distro.

Comment: He is talking about the server version and I too believe those directories are not part of a default server installation. At least, as a admin I believe, they should not be part of it ;)

Comment: They're under /home/"Username", however, they weren't there when I first installed 12.04. And as Rinzwind pointed out, it would be rather silly to include those directories on a server installation.

Answer (score -1):

These are always present in **any** Ubuntu installation. Nothing to worry about.